# Testing Activity Recognition Transition API

Tags: android, android-activity, transition

I am currently developing an app which uses Activity Recognition Transition API (the new one, not the old, check the link below). My question is, how can I test my app? More exactly, how can I "manually" trigger transition events? Do I really have to put my phone and laptop into my backpack and go for a ride on a bicycle to trigger the ON_BYCICLE/ACTIVITY_TRANSITION_ENTER event? There must be an easier way :) Maybe using adb? https://developer.android.com/studio/test/command-line

API documentation: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/transitions

Comment: Maybe this sample could help: https://github.com/AndroidDeveloperLB/UserActivityRecognitionSample

Answer (score 1):

You can use following code to emulate the event

```
        var intent = Intent()

        // Your broadcast receiver action

        intent.action = BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + "TRANSITIONS_RECEIVER_ACTION"
        var events: ArrayList<ActivityTransitionEvent> = arrayListOf()

        // You can set desired events with their corresponding state

        var transitionEvent = ActivityTransitionEvent(DetectedActivity.IN_VEHICLE, ActivityTransition.ACTIVITY_TRANSITION_ENTER, SystemClock.elapsedRealtimeNanos())
        events.add(transitionEvent)
        var result = ActivityTransitionResult(events)
        SafeParcelableSerializer.serializeToIntentExtra(result, intent, "com.google.android.location.internal.EXTRA_ACTIVITY_TRANSITION_RESULT")
        activity?.sendBroadcast(intent)
```

I have created simple activity with two buttons in my application where I broadcast these events(Start and Stop) respectively. This helps me debug the application gracefully.

Comment: I had to use LocalBroadcastManager to send broadcast.

Comment: What are you supposed to use as intent action?

Comment: @Ananth How to use SafeParcelableSerializer?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any way to simulate a transition event from outside your app. But within your app, you can construct a suitable `Intent` and send it to your receiver.

Add this method to any `Context` (e.g. an `Activity` or `Service`): (Kotlin)

```kotlin
class MyService: Service() {
  fun sendFakeActivityTransitionEvent() {
    // name your intended recipient class
    val intent = Intent(this, MyReceiver::class.java)
    
    val events: ArrayList<ActivityTransitionEvent> = arrayListOf()
    
    // create fake events
    events.add(
      ActivityTransitionEvent(
        DetectedActivity.ON_BICYCLE,
        ActivityTransition.ACTIVITY_TRANSITION_ENTER,
        SystemClock.elapsedRealtimeNanos()
      )
    )
    
    // finally, serialize and send
    val result = ActivityTransitionResult(events)
    SafeParcelableSerializer.serializeToIntentExtra(
      result,
      intent,
      "com.google.android.location.internal.EXTRA_ACTIVITY_TRANSITION_RESULT"
    )
    this.sendBroadcast(intent)
  }
}
```

Substitute your desired recipient for `MyReceiver` -- any subclass of `BroadcastReceiver` should work.

Then call `sendFakeActivityTransitionEvent()` when desired.